# how to reduce the noise of an image on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

This is my code so far. I am totally lost and not sure what to do. its python language. I cant use cv2 or matpolibic. I am only allowed to use cimpl and numpy

```
from Cimpl import*
import numpy as np 
def reduce_noise (image: Image) -> Image:
    new_image = copy(image)
    for pixel in image:
        X, Y, (r, g, b) = pixel

        r_list = [r, r1, r2, r3, r4]
        r_list.sort()
        new_r = r_list[2]
        
        g_list = [g, g1, g2, g3, g4]
        g_list.sort()
        new_g = g_list[2]
        
        b_list = [b, b1, b2, b3, b4]
        b_list.sort()
        new_b = b_list[2]
        reduce_noise = create_color(new_r, new_g, new_b)
        set_color(new_image, X, Y, reduce_noise)
        
    return new_image

image = load_image (choose_file())
show (image) 
new_image = reduce_noise(image)
show (new_image)
```

Comment: One simplest way to reduce noise is to do blur by just computing value of each pixel equal to average of 3x3 or 5x5 pixels around it. As I can see in your code you tried (although with coding mistakes) to compute median of some pixels around it, also a way.

Comment: This looks like the beginning of a median filter, which would be somewhat effective against noise.  But it's not at all complete, you don't define `r1`-`r4`, `g1`-`g4`, or `b1`-`b4`.

Comment: @alex I used your idea of implementing median filter and improved it to use pure Numpy, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66395675/941531) below.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1** (See also Part 2 below)

I decided to improve your attempt of denoising algorithm. As I can see by your code you tried (with coding mistakes) to implement median filter, taking median of several pixels around each pixel.

I implemented next algorithm in pure Numpy. But to read and write image from/to file I used PIL library, just replace this PIL usage with anything you like that reads and writes to file a numpy array. I used PIL only on first and last lines of code. PIL library just for testing can be installed by `pip install pillow`, it is one of the most popular imaging library in python.

In next algorithm strength of median filter is controlled by `n` parameter which equals to 7 in my case. Value `n` means that we take median among pixels of square of size `n` by `n`.

My code works both with gray and color images, see gray examples after the code and colored examples after gray examples.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66395494var2#main.py)

```
def reduce_noise(a, n = 7):
    import numpy as np
    am = np.zeros(
        (n, n) + (a.shape[0] - n + 1, a.shape[1] - n + 1) + a.shape[2:],
        dtype = a.dtype
    )
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            am[i, j] = a[i:i + am.shape[2], j:j + am.shape[3]]
    am = np.moveaxis(am, (0, 1), (-2, -1)).reshape(*am.shape[2:], -1)
    am = np.median(am, axis = -1)
    if am.dtype != a.dtype:
        am = (am.astype(np.float64) + 10 ** -7).astype(a.dtype)
    return am
    
import PIL.Image, numpy as np
a = np.array(PIL.Image.open('noised.jpg'))
a = reduce_noise(a)
PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save('noised_out.png')
```

Gray example (colored example afterwards):

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Colored example:

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

---

**Part 2**

My appologies, by mistake I missread your question, instead of "I cant use cv2" I read "I can use cv2", and hence implemented next OpenCV algorithm as my first attempt to solve your task (Part-1 algorithm was implemented later).

According to [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html) OpenCV denoising tutorial you can denoise your image like in code below. It uses [cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d79/group__photo__denoise.html#ga03aa4189fc3e31dafd638d90de335617) function, there is also grayscale variant of this function if you have gray image.

Degree of denoising is controlled by `20, 20, 14, 42` params in my code, it is very strong denoising, you can use default values (without providing these numbers), it will give smaller denoising degree. For your image start with default values of `3, 3, 7, 21`, maybe they're enough, no need for very strong denoising, and experiment with these values.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66395494#main.py)

```
import numpy as np, cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('birds.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img, None, 20, 20, 14, 42)
cv2.imwrite('birds_out.png', cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
plt.subplot(121); plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(122); plt.imshow(dst)
plt.show()
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: I can't use matplotlib. Also, I am only allowed to use one parameter which  needs to be an image. Can you please show me how I would convert your code into that

Comment: @alex Please put a look into Part 2 of my question, first sentences, I told there that I implemented Part 2 only by mistake. So actual correct solution is **Part 1** at beginning of my answer. There algorithm uses only Numpy. Use that algorithm. In Part 1 function `reduce_noise()` has only one parameter, everyone can call it just like this `reduce_noise(img)`. Second parameter is optional, you don't need to use it in a call. You can actually remove it, just remove it from function and add first line of function body as `n = 7`, i.e. just move this `n` parameter to first line of code body.

Comment: @alex Also, param `n = 7` controls strength of noise reduction. To remove noise stronger increase it, resulting image will be more denoised but also more blurred. To remove noise less decrease it, then image will become less blur but can still have some noise left. In real life probably good value is `n = 5`, if noise is not strong you may use `n = 3`. Just a small advice, if possible, use odd values for `n`, i.e. 1 3 5 7 9 11, better not to use 2 4 8 10 12 (but still possible, there will be no error). Just experiment with different values of `n`.

Comment: @alex If finally my answer will be correct for you don't forget to Accept it and/or UpVote it too. Accept/UpVote can be done at the top of my answer, to the left from top. There is CheckMark to accept and Upper arrow to upvote.

Comment: what would i define (a) to be as I am not using it as a parameter? like shown in the code a.shape I am not sure what exactly it means nor how to use it or assign it

Comment: @alex `reduce_noise()` should be passed only a Numpy array, `a` is input numpy array. If you have colored RGB image of width 300 and height 200 then your array `a` will be of size `200x300x3` (200 rows, 300 columns, 3 colors), just a regular numpy array of `dtype = np.uint8`. In my example I used PIL library to convert PNG/JPG file into numpy array, but in your case you probably have to use your own library for reading images that you have. Most of imaging libraries operate and support numpy arrays.