# How do I remove the noise on this image in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have the following image:

[image]

I would like to remove some of the noise in this image. I have already tried to use OpenCV with the following code:

```
cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(image_sharp, None, 2, 10, 7, 20)
```

However the image that is returned back to me appears the exact same:

[image: Denoised image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You can try this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66395494/how-to-reduce-the-noise-of-an-image-on-python) using PIL module

Comment: Please, add a proper [mcve] (i.e. complete script with imports, etc. that we can run to reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 5):

You can do division normalization in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Apply GaussianBlur
- Divide the grayscale image by the blurred image
- Save the output

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('equation.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, None, sigmaX=100, sigmaY=100)

# divide gray by morphology image
division = cv2.divide(gray, smooth, scale=255)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('equation_division.jpg',division)

# show results
cv2.imshow('smooth', smooth)  
cv2.imshow('division', division)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]